# How to get Embeded/nested XML from a big XML file using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

We are performing some operations on embedded/Nested XML.I am using SAXParser to parse the entire XML file.I want to get the entire nested XML with tags and value.For example my XML looks like.

I want entire XML within the `<ANY_ELEMENT>`.....<`/ANY-ELEMENT>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <x:xMessage xmlns:x="http://www.connecture.com/integration/x" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.connecture.com/integration/x xMessageWrapper.xsd
                ">
                <x:xMessageHeader>
                    <Version>850</Version>
                    <Source>Source</Source>
                    <Target>target</Target>
                    <Timestamp>2013-12-31T12:00:00</Timestamp>
                    <RequestID>123456</RequestID>
                    <ResponseID>54321</ResponseID>
                    <Priority>3</Priority>
                    <Username>Deepak</Username>
                    <Password>Kumar</Password>
                </x:xMessageHeader>
                <x:xMessageBody>
                    <ANY-ELEMENT>
                        <xEnveloped_834A1 xsi:schemaLocation="....." xmlns="......."
                            ..........................
                    ..........................
                            some Complex XML
                        ..........................
                        ..........................
                        ..........................

                    </ANY-ELEMENT>

                 </x:XMessageBody>
        </x:XMessage>
```

**Handler class Sample code:**

```
public class MessageWrapperHandler extends DefaultHandler {


    private boolean bActualMessage = false;
    private String actualMessage = null;
    private long lengthActualMessage=0;



    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {

      if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ANY-ELEMENT")) {
            bActualMessage = true;
            //lengthActualMessage=How to know the length of Child XML
        }
    }
  public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {

         if (bActualMessage) {
            actualMessage = new String(ch, start, length);
            //trying to get embedded XML
            bActualMessage = false;
        }
    }

}
```

But since next element after  is XML content so giving me nothing.SO How to achieve it.
**EDIT:** You are free to modify XML after `<ANY-ELEMENT>` like adding contents into `CDATA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of SAX, I would recommend using StAX (a StAX implementation is included in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6).  StAX is similar to SAX except instead of having the events pushed to you, you pull (request) them.

In the code below the `XMLStreamReader` is advanced to the `ANY-ELEMENT` element.  Once it is at the correct position you can interact with it as you wish.

```
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();

        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource("src/forum19559825/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xmlSource);

        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.positionXMLStreamReaderAtAnyElement(xsr);
        demo.processAnyElement(xsr);
    }

    private void positionXMLStreamReaderAtAnyElement(XMLStreamReader xsr) throws Exception {
        while(xsr.hasNext()) {
            if(xsr.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT && "ANY-ELEMENT".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {
                break;
            }
            xsr.next();
        }
    }

    private void processAnyElement(XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReaderAtAnyElement) {
        // TODO: Stuff
        System.out.println("FOUND IT");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Blasise for your answer.For the time being i just putted the all data between <ANY-ELEMENT> and </ANY-ELEMENT> into CDATA and the same code is working.